# Primefaces SelectOneMenu selects item when ctrl+key (hotkey) is pressed

Tags: javascript, primefaces, keyboard-shortcuts, selectonemenu

I have some JSF forms with hotkeys, e.g., <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> will save the data.

The problem is, when a key combination is pressed and the focus is on a `<p:selectOneMenu>` field, the first item starting with `S` (following the example) is selected and then the form is submitted.

You can reproduce this behavior in the [showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/selectOneMenu.jsf), in the first field, pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>. In Chrome, at least, it'll select the first Option and then the browser "Open Dialog".

I want this component ignores the letter when a special key is pressed.

I've tested this behavior against `SELECT` html element and "combo box" from jQuery UI, but and it simply doesn't happen. Primefaces implementation of SelectOneMenu is a different wrapper to an input field.

I tried `return false` in both `onkeyup` and `onkeydown` attributes that are listed in PF User Guide. No results.

I tried also adding jQuery keyboard event listeners with `preventDefault()` and `return false`. Nothing.

Before digging into the PrimeFaces code I'd like to know if there's a known workaround for this case.

Comment: The problem discussed in PF forum: http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=38020&p=124953

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I checked out a newer version of PrimeFaces source from SVN repository. There were some Javascript functions fixed in the component.

Then I extracted those fixed functions and put them in a Javascript file in order to override the original ones.

The code is as follows:

```js
/**
 * Fix for selectOneMenu when key is pressed along with CTRL
 */
PrimeFaces.widget.SelectOneMenu = PrimeFaces.widget.SelectOneMenu.extend({

    bindKeyEvents: function() {
        var $this = this;

        this.focusInput.on('keydown.ui-selectonemenu', function(e) {
            var keyCode = $.ui.keyCode,
            key = e.which;

            switch(key) {
                case keyCode.UP:
                case keyCode.LEFT:
                    $this.highlightPrev(e);
                break;

                case keyCode.DOWN:
                case keyCode.RIGHT:
                    $this.highlightNext(e);
                break;

                case keyCode.ENTER:
                case keyCode.NUMPAD_ENTER:
                    $this.handleEnterKey(e);
                break;

                case keyCode.TAB:
                    $this.handleTabKey();
                break;

                case keyCode.ESCAPE:
                    $this.handleEscapeKey(e);
                break;
            }
        })
        .on('keyup.ui-selectonemenu', function(e) {
            var keyCode = $.ui.keyCode,
            key = e.which;
            switch(key) {
                case keyCode.UP:
                case keyCode.LEFT:
                case keyCode.DOWN:
                case keyCode.RIGHT:
                case keyCode.ENTER:
                case keyCode.NUMPAD_ENTER:
                case keyCode.TAB:
                case keyCode.ESCAPE:
                break;

                default:
                    var text = $(this).val(),
                    matchedOptions = null;

                    clearTimeout($this.searchTimer);

                    matchedOptions = $this.options.filter(function() {
                        return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(text.toLowerCase()) === 0;
                    });

                    if(matchedOptions.length) {
                        var highlightItem = $this.items.eq(matchedOptions.index());
                        if($this.panel.is(':hidden')) {
                            $this.selectItem(highlightItem);
                        }
                        else {
                            $this.highlightItem(highlightItem);
                            PrimeFaces.scrollInView($this.itemsWrapper, highlightItem);
                        }
                    }

                    $this.searchTimer = setTimeout(function(){
                        $this.focusInput.val('');
                    }, 1000);

                break;
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: You say: "I checked out a newer version of PrimeFaces source from SVN repository", but in 5.0.8 I still see this problem.
Which -SNAPSHOT did you use? Was it a 5.1-SNAPSHOT?

Comment: @alfonx I'd got revision 10632 from SVN trunk at that time. I've tried also the [new component in show case](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/oneMenu.xhtml) right now and it won't select items when I hold <kbd>CTRL</kbd> or other special key. On the other hand, PF has a lot of little bugs and regressions aren't uncommon. Actually I don't recommend JSF for new projects at all, unless you have very low standards and short time for such application.

Comment: I can reproduce the bug with Firefox 28 on Linux in the 5.0.8 Showcase: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/oneMenu.xhtml

Comment: @alfonx Interesting. I haven't linux at work, but as soon as I get home I'll test it with my VirtualBox. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading to Primefaces 5.1.9 (or 5.2 if you are not an ELITE customer) fixes this for CTRL, ALT and SHIFT.

The 5.0 branch contains this fix in 5.0.16

Here is the Releasenot: http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=3415

Here is the Ticket: https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=7892